# SQL query to find audit logs of session login and logout and pg_audit in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I am using Postgres in RDS instance. I have enabled log_connections and log_disconnections parameter and also setup pg_audit extension to capture changes for DDL. I would like to know that is there any SQL query for looking at the logs of session login and logout and pg_audit DDL changes for any date. Manually looking at log file every time becomes much tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till date, I couldn't find any alternative apart from looking at logs file.